# Remove unselected value from dropdown array - ngx-select-dropdown

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ngx-select-dropdown

*context*: Angular applications using the ngx-select-dropdown. A user can select multiple values, these values get sorted into "buckets" and sent  to the api.

*Issue*: I am unable to remove a selected item from the end array - this.filterState. I have added a check to ensure that an item cant be added more than once - a click to select the item and a click to deselect the item. I thought that this would be a good time to remove the item with a `splice` as the user would have clicked to deselect if it already exists in the array - however, the dropdown does not pass the value of a deselected object it just removes it from the value array of the dropdown.

```
  const index = this.filterState[convertedParam].indexOf(value);

  if (index === -1) {
    this.filterState[convertedParam].push(value);
  }
```

*Proposed solution*: I think it will need some sort of comparison upon event change against the dropdown value object and the array that was previously sent to the api.

*End goal*: To be able to add and remove objects from the sorted array

[Here is a stackblitz that I put together..](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-select-dropdown-xkfbyr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

**app.component.ts**

```
  handleFilterChange(prop: string, value: any): void {

// I think the comparison with "value" and whats already in "this.filterState" will need to be done here?

    let field = this.fields.find(f => f.name === prop);

    if (field.params) {
      value.forEach(v => this.setFilterState(v.type, v, field));
    } else {
      this.setFilterState(prop, value, field);
    }
    console.log("SUBMITTED SORTED VALUES", this.filterState);
  }

  setFilterState(prop: string, value: any, field: Field): void {
    const colourParamMap = {
      I_am_RED: "reds",
      I_am_BLUE: "blues",
      I_am_GREEN: "greens"
    };

    if (field.name === "multiselect_1") {

      const convertedParam = colourParamMap[prop];

      const index = this.filterState[convertedParam].indexOf(value);

      //stops from adding same value again and adds value to array
      if (index === -1) {
        this.filterState[convertedParam].push(value);
      }

    } else {
      //There will be more logic here
      this.filterState[prop] = value;
    }
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-select-dropdown-xkfbyr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I just ran your stackblitz and everything seems to be working fine based on your end goal: "End goal: To be able to add and remove objects from the sorted array". I used "r" and "red" search phrases and I was able to successfully select and deselect items. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: No they are not being removed. If you open up the console - add a red from the dropdown it populates the red array. Then remove the red you just selected and the red array remains populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix in the end - I was trying to over complicate things. I needed to reset the `this.filterState` as the value from the dropdown will include every value from before, minus the ones that were deselected.

```
  handleFilterChange(prop: string, value: any): void {
    this.filterState = {
      reds: [],
      blues: [],
      greens: []
    };
```